# Large image matrix: save to small matrices

Tags: matlab

I'm new to MATLAB and its development. I have a image which is 1134 (rows) X 1134 (columns). I want that image to save 3 (columns) X 3 (rows). In order to do that I need 378 cells. For that I used following code, but it gives me an error.

```
 image=imread('C:\Users\ven\Desktop\test\depth.png');
    I=reshape(image,1,1134*1134);
    chunk_size = [3 3]; % your desired size of the chunks image is broken into
    sc = sz ./ chunk_size; % number of chunks in each dimension; must be integer

    % split to chunk_size(1) by chunk_size(2) chunks
    X = mat2cell(I, chunk_size(1) * ones(sc(1),1), chunk_size(2) *ones(sc(2),1));
```

Error:

> Error using mat2cell (line 97)
>   Input arguments, D1 through D2, must sum to each dimension of the input matrix size, [1  1285956].'

Comment: What were you expecting this code to do? `./` is the element-wise divide operator. It tries to divide each element of the LHS with the *corresponding* element on the RHS. The key word here is corresponding, meaning that the two matrices *must* have the identical number of elements and the same shape. I'm afraid your code doesn't even come close to do what you describe. Can I suggest you read http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-vs-matrix-operations.html and the [documentation for `./`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/rdivide.html) and a basic tutorial for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Behind the `C=A./B` command is loop over all elements of `A(ii,jj,...)` and `B(ii,jj,..)` and each `C(ii,jj,..)=A(ii,jj,...)/B(ii,jj,...)`.

Therefore martices `A` and `B` must be of same dimension.

If you want to split matrix into groups you can use

```
sc=cell(1134/3,1);
kk=0;ll=0;
for ii=2:3:1133
 kk=kk+1;
 for jj=2:3:1133
   ll=ll+1;
   sc{kk,ll}=image(ii-1:ii+1,jj-1:jj+1);
 end
end
```

The code allocates cell array `sc` for resulting submatrices and arbitrary counters `kk` and `ll`. Then it loops over `ii` and `jj` with step of 3 representing centers of each submatrices.

---

**Edit**

Or you can use `mat2cell` command (type `help mat2cell` or `doc mat2cell` in matlab shell)

```
sc=mat2cell(image,3,3);
```

In both cases the result is **cell array** and its `ii`th and `jj`th elements (matrices) are accessible by `sc{ii,jj}`. If you want call `ii`th anr `jj`th number in `kk`th and `ll`th matrix, do it via `sc{kk,ll}(ii,jj)`.

Comment: @Crowley could you please explain me for ii=2:3:1133 , All i know ii=2:3 please.

Comment: @VenSan The answer is more complicated, so I've expanded it in another question; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36574423/how-does-for-loop-work-in-matlab/36574651#36574651

Comment: @VenSan In short, it defines array with elements `[2,5,8,...,1133]` and in every loop it assign appropriate value to `ii` variable.

Comment: @Crowley thank you so much. I extended program but again i'm having a Error. I'm very thank ful if you can please look at it. i want to make sure that where i'm mistaken. thank you so much.

Comment: @Error using mat2cell (line 97) Input arguments, D1 through D2, must sum to each dimension of the input matrix size, [1 1285956].'

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately your code does not work as you think it would.

The `./` operator performs point wise division of two matrices. Short example:

```
[12, 8] ./ [4, 2] == [12/4, 8/2] == [3, 4]
```

In order for it to work both matrices must have exactly the same size. In your case you try to perform such an operation on a 1134x1134 matrix (the image) and a 1x2 matrix (chunk_size).

In other words you can not use it to divide matrices into smaller ones.

However, a solution to your problem is to use the `mat2cell` function to pick out subsets of the matrix. A explanation of how it is done can be found here (including examples): http://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/89757-how-to-divide-256x256-matrix-into-sixteen-16x16-blocks.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: In case that link one day breaks, I suggest that you also incorporate the gist of the solution (i.e. use `mat2cell`) in your answer as well.

Comment: @rasan076 i got it. I've already voted your answer. But now i extented my question. with what i have learnt. could you please take a look my question. I want to make sure that where i'm mistaken. thank you.

Comment: @VenSan please don't do that, if you have a new question based on what you learned then please ask it as a new question.

Comment: @Dan i got it. I'm sorry. next time i will ask new Question. so sorry.

Answer (score 1):

In short, you divided a 1134 x 1134 by 2 x 1 matrix. That doesn't work.

The error "Matrix dimensions must agree**" is from the dividing a matrix with another matrix that doesn't have the right dimensions.

You used the scalar divide "./" which divided a matrix by another matrix.

You want something like:

```
n = 1134 / 3         % you should measure the length of the image
I1=image(1:n,1:n);   % first row
I2=image(1:n,n:2n);
I3=image(1:n,2n:3n);
I4=image(n:2n,1:n); % second row
I5=image(n:2n,n:2n);
I6=image(n:2n,2n:3n);
I7=image(2n:3n,1:n); % third row
I8=image(2n:3n,n:2n);
I9=image(2n:3n,2n:3n);
```

from here:
http://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/46699-how-to-segment-divide-an-image-into-4-equal-halves

There would be a nice loop you could do it in, but sometimes thinking is hard.

Comment: At the very least use cell arrays instead of cluttering the workspace with all those variables! Also, OP want *3*-by-*3* matrices, not to divide into 3 matrices so you'd have to go up to `n` there...

Comment: Yeah, it is a crude solution that clutters the work space with variables. You are right. But Ven didn't know how to use arrays in the first place. So it might help him. I would hate for him to deal with 9 arrays inside one array, as a 3 dimensional array. He is struggling with a 2D array and a 1D array. In that way, I think crude is better.

By go up to 'n' you mean up to 1134? 3n = 1134

Comment: `n` would be `1134/3` but actually you have to go up to `n^2` which is `142884` so you would need 150 thousand individually named variables... so in this case the crude solution is not even an option. Unless I misunderstood the OP, question is very ambiguous. Either way, this solution should never be used. Cell arrays are a basic structure in MATLAB and anyone using the language needs to learn how to use them.

Comment: No, I think I misunderstood the question. I think you got it right. I think cell arrays are the most useful thing about Matlab as a programming language.

Comment: I feel awkward about getting up voted when I misunderstood the question.